# How to determine relationship between two entities when there is more than one relation while creating distant supervision training data?

Tags: nlp, information-extraction

I got the concepts of distant supervision. As for my understanding, the creating training data process is like;

- Extract named entities from sentences
- Find two entities named "e1" and "e2" from each sentence.
- Search these two entities in knowledge base (freebase etc.) to find relationship between them

I got confused at this step. What if there is more than 1 relation between these two entities (e1 and e2) ? If so which relation should I select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the model you're training.

Are you learning a model for one kind of relationship and doing bootstrapping? Then only pay attention to that one relationship and drop the others from your DB.

Are you trying to learn a bunch of relationships? Then use the presence or absence of each as a feature in your model. This is how [Universals Schemas](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/N13-1008/) work.

Here's an image of a feature matrix from the Universal Schema paper:

[image: Feature matrix from Universal Schemas]